# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.car.developeroptions.action.DEMO_MODE }

Tags: android, android-automotive

I am trying to use the SystemUI demo mode using the AAOS emulator (see image below), but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

[image: AAOS Q emulator dev options]

The build number is as shown here:

[image: AAOS Q emulator build number]

Logcat shows the following exception. I am wondering if this is a known issue and if it can be avoided somehow?

```
Process: com.android.car.developeroptions, PID: 4461
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.car.developeroptions.action.DEMO_MODE }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2058)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1716)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5211)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5169)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5540)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5508)
    at androidx.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:1199)
    at androidx.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:1166)
    at androidx.preference.Preference$1.onClick(Preference.java:181)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7259)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7236)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27892)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 0):

the RenderService has not been supported on the AAOS, currently just testing the car templates-related apps on the Android Auto and using the DHU as the projected terminal. see details of the NOTES on the official webpage: [Usage of Android for cars](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps)